# How can I convert string timestamp column to timestamp in grafana

Tags: timestamp, grafana, vertica

I'm using PG plugin for vertica in grafana because grafana don't have native Vertica plugin

```
select date_trunc('hour', moment) as time,
       sum(netSlaes)              as netSales
from ba.table
group by time;
```

Grafana tells that:

```
Invalid type for column time, must be of type timestamp or unix timestamp, got: string 2019-05-28 22:00:00
```

But when I use DataGrip this sql returns:

```
2019-05-28 05:00:00.000000  1456106.03030303
2019-05-28 11:00:00.000000  16463313.9090909
2019-05-28 13:00:00.000000  15796558.4818182
2019-05-28 14:00:00.000000  5134891.6969697
2019-05-28 20:00:00.000000  13058329.5909091
...
```

Please help with timestamp format for time column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vertica developers added their plugin for grafana: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vertica-grafana-datasource/installation

about 4 months ago

Answer (score 1):

Try to extract the unix timestamp (epoch) from your column using `DATE_PART`, and cast it to `INT`.

```
select date_part('EPOCH', date_trunc('hour', moment))::INT as time,
       sum(netSlaes)              as netSales
from ba.table
group by time;
```

P.S - 
I tried to make PG Grafana's plugin to work with Vertica in the past, and also encountered those kind of data types problems. If I remember correctly there was a problem with integers considered to be strings.

Comment: I made adapter based on lib pq with vertica types https://github.com/frankegoesdown/pq/blob/master/oid/types.go but grafana uses xorm and I must patch xorm too... So tomorrow I'll try to write plugin for vertica